# PyInstaller stuck in an infinite loop (hooks)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a launcher for my game. I already succeeded in making the parts that would automatically update my game. What I am trying to do now is to turn the generated (or updated) python code into an executable with PyInstaller. I am using this code to do so:

```
from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
[code that generates main.py and it's dependencies]
run(["main.py", "--onefile", "-w"])
```

When I ran the launcher as a python file, it works perfectly as I would expect. But after I convert the launcher.py into launcher.exe with PyInstaller, it no longer works. The error being:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launcher.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 480, in get_distribution
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 356, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 899, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 785, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyInstaller' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[16788] Failed to execute script launcher
```

I did some research and found out that I have to add a hook for PyInstaller itself. I did that and  another error message appeared:

```
 File "launcher.py", line 55, in <module>
    run(["main.py", "--onefile", "-w"])
  File "PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 81, in run
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "altgraph\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 899, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 785, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'altgraph' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[6716] Failed to execute script launcher
```

Again, I added a hook for "altgraph", then this happened:

```
5204 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
5204 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
5212 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
5212 INFO: wrote E:\编程\Python\Still working\2D Minecraft\Launcher test\main.spec
5220 INFO: UPX is not available.
5220 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test',
 'E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test']
5220 INFO: checking Analysis
5228 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
5236 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
5236 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
5236 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5342 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
5342 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
5342 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
5350 INFO: wrote E:\编程\Python\Still working\2D Minecraft\Launcher test\main.spec
5350 INFO: UPX is not available.
5358 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test',
 'E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test']
5366 INFO: checking Analysis
5366 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
5366 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
5374 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
5382 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
7309 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
7309 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
7309 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
7317 INFO: wrote E:\编程\Python\Still working\2D Minecraft\Launcher test\main.spec
7325 INFO: UPX is not available.
7325 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test',
 'E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test']
7333 INFO: checking Analysis
7333 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
7333 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
7341 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
7349 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6976 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
6976 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
6984 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
6984 INFO: wrote E:\编程\Python\Still working\2D Minecraft\Launcher test\main.spec
6992 INFO: UPX is not available.
6992 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test',
 'E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test']
7000 INFO: checking Analysis
7000 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
7000 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
7000 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
7008 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
```

It went into an infinite loop repeating these messages:

```
6976 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
6976 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
6984 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
6984 INFO: wrote E:\编程\Python\Still working\2D Minecraft\Launcher test\main.spec
6992 INFO: UPX is not available.
6992 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test',
 'E:\\编程\\Python\\Still working\\2D Minecraft\\Launcher test']
7000 INFO: checking Analysis
7000 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
7000 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
7000 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
7008 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
```

I had it running for a while and it went on forever
(Note that altgraph was not imported in my game so I'm also slightly confused on that part)

Comment: try using auto-py-to-exe

Comment: can you run that directly with python code? or does it have to be in the console

Comment: go to command prompt and type auto-py-to-exe to run it once u have installed it

Comment: did it work @Andrew DaNub?

Comment: What I'm trying to do was to create a launcher.py, convert it into exe which I can send to others (which I can already do with PyInstaller). When launcher.exe is executed, it is going to run a script that creates a main.py, then convert main.py to exe, so it has to be done with python code, without the involvement of the command prompt, which is exactly what I'm struggling to do. I already can make an exe with PyInstaller in the command prompt, the problem is converting py to exe **within** another exe.

Comment: then simply change it from console based to window based in auto-py-to-exe

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my problem, because I do know how auto-py-to-exe works and it would not solve my problem.

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried my best to explain it in the above comment, and also I described it in detail in the post itself.

Comment: Ok idk if this might be clearer but, auto-py-to-exe requires a user interface, the user has to do something to convert py to exe. What I want is have an exe file (created from a py file manually) that automatically converts another py file to exe, by only having the user double click it. But when I try to do this, the errors that I described in the post happens.